# python: How to set F_NOTIFY from non-main thread?

Tags: python, linux, signals, fcntl

I am trying to watch a directory using F_NOTIFY in Linux (Ubuntu 16, Python 3.5.2). However, it only works if I call `fcntl` from the main thread. Why are there no signals when I call `fcntl` from other threads? (I don't see any mention of threads in the python [`fcntl` documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/fcntl.html#module-fcntl). Also, if `fcntl` is failing, why doesn't it throw an exception?)

```
# Before running, create directory "a". To test, create a file in "a".

import fcntl, signal, os, threading

pipe_r, pipe_w = os.pipe()
def Unsafe_Handler(s,f):
    os.write(pipe_w, b' ')
signal.signal(signal.SIGIO, Unsafe_Handler)
signal.siginterrupt(signal.SIGIO, False)
def Handler():
    while True:
        os.read(pipe_r, 1)
        print("SIGNAL")
threading.Thread(target = Handler).start()

NOTIF_FLAGS = fcntl.DN_MODIFY | fcntl.DN_CREATE | fcntl.DN_MULTISHOT

def Watch_Dir(dn):
    fd = os.open(dn, os.O_RDONLY)
    fcntl.fcntl(fd, fcntl.F_SETSIG, 0)
    fcntl.fcntl(fd, fcntl.F_NOTIFY, NOTIF_FLAGS)
    print('Watching directory "%s", fd=%d' % (dn, fd))
    return fd

def Init():
    fd = Watch_Dir('a')


# this works
#Init()

# this doesn't work
t = threading.Thread(target = Init)
t.start()
t.join()


print("Awaiting signals...")
while True:
    signal.pause()
```

**Why signal handling in Python requires threads**

The `Handler` thread is required because of the following combination of facts:

1. The handler attached with `signal.signal` can't safely do anything but write to a pipe.
2. The main thread can't do real work either, for two reasons. First, because most blocking calls in the main thread will [prevent the signal from being handled](https://github.com/python/cpython/issues/85300). Second, since the only allowed call is `signal.pause()`, there is no way to safely wake up the main thread without a race condition (signal arrives just before the `signal.pause()`) that could get the main thread stuck.

**Why calling `fcntl` from the non-main thread is useful**

This is simply because the main thread can't do real work, as already noted. (In my actual application, the handler needs to call `fcntl`. For this question I've created a simpler example though).

Comment: I think it has less to do with `fcntl` failing but rather signals in generally don't play nice with threads, see [issue python/cpython#66094](https://github.com/python/cpython/issues/66094)

Comment: @metatoaster I've added a section at the end of the question to explain why threads are in fact *required* to use signals *at all* in python.

Comment: Sure, it's not that I don't appreciate your explanation or your particular needs, but there may be issues with how Python does things that impact the specific needs that you have. Specifically, you might need to appreciate [this comment](https://github.com/python/cpython/issues/66094#issuecomment-1093658561) in the very issue I linked, strongly implying that python signal handlers currently can only run in the main thread, and the other comments strongly imply that none of this is currently safe (i.e. dead locks and race conditions) should that run outside the main thread.

Comment: Moreover, given that the code requires that the `Unsafe_Handler` be set up to listen at the main thread, it wouldn't exactly be able to call `signal.pause` from another thread to be able to trigger this, right? (Never mind that it isn't possible to call that from outside the main thread, given `ValueError: signal only works in main thread of the main interpreter` is raised if that is attempted.)

Comment: Finally, please appreciate that in the `F_NOTIFY` section of the relevant [man page for `fcntl`](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fcntl.2.html) states that "New applications should use the `inotify` interface (available since Linux 2.6.13), which provides a much superior interface for obtaining notifications of filesystem events." This may be done by using the [`watchfiles`](https://pypi.org/project/watchfiles/) package (which is cross-platform, and on Linux it does use `inotify` underneath the hood via the Rust package `notify`).